# Material thickness, thermal conductivity and electrical resistivity

Tags: thermodynamics, electrostatics, electrical-resistance, estimation, thermal-conductivity

I have a plastic housing (for a printed circuit board- PCB) in the shape of a box (a *b *c) with L (thickness). Its material properties are:

*thermal conductivity:                              $k_h~[Wm^{-1}K{-1}]$

*specific electrical resistance:                    $\sigma_h [\Omega m]$

(elastic modulus:                                   $\lambda_h [2600N/mm^2])$

thermal contact 1:  area of plastic and copper:          $M = 50*20 mm^2$

thermal contact 2:  area of plastic and PCB:             $N = 10*30 mm^2$

temperature inside housing minus temperature ambiental:  $dT = (60 - 27)K$

I would like to know how heat conduction and electrical resistivity are changing with thickness $L$. So I can find the optimal $L$.

Comment: Electrical resistivity is a material property. It does not change with the dimensions of the object.

Answer (score 0):

The flow of both current and heat depend on the *gradient* (for current: gradient of voltage over distance, i.e. electric field; for heat: temperature difference over distance). If you increase the thickness, you increase the thermal resistance perpendicular to the walls.

Note - both thermal and electrical conductivity are functions of temperature. You indicate rather low temperatures: it might matter to make sure that you are using the correct values of conductivity (and not, for example, values at room temperature).